# Trying to get an array from arrays.xml into a ListView using a custom ArrayAdapter class. What's wrong?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It Eclipse isn't giving me any errors or warnings, but my ListView isn't being populated when i run the emulator. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**This is inside onCreate:**

```
ListView bedList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.refineBeds);
bedList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
bedList.setAdapter(new MArrayAdapter(this, R.array.beds));
bedList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

**This is a custom inner class I'm trying to use as my adapter:**

```
private static class MArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public MArrayAdapter(final Context context, final int objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_single, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final CheckedTextView view = (CheckedTextView)
    super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    view.setChecked(position == 2); return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the xml for the array you are trying to load.

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors in the XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try first without a cusom layout like this, then eventually you can adjust it using your own layout:

```
...

String[] bedsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.beds);

bedList.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                           this,
                           android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
                           bedsArray));

...
```

Comment: I just needed to create the string array using the getResources.getStringArray as you mentioned. Then simply add the String[] to my constructor, all is well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this line below

```
new MArrayAdapter(this, R.array.beds)
```

This corresponds to following definition

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId)
```

Try creating a List of string elements from R.array.beds and use the following constructor

```
public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```